# Show that $b_nb_k\mid b_{n+k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

Let ${a_n}$ be sequence such that $\forall n,k\in\mathbb{N}, a_n\mid a_{n+k}-a_k$ and, let $b_n=\Pi^{n}_{i=1} a_i$. Then prove that $\forall n, k\in\mathbb{N}, b_nb_k\mid b_{n+k}$.

$a_i=ci, c\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the condition:
I'll prove $m!k!\mid (m+k)!$. $p\in\mathbb{P}$, let $\upsilon_p(a)=k\iff p^k\mid\mid a$. $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}$, $\upsilon_p(\frac{(m+k)!}{m!k!})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}([\frac{m+k}{p^i}]-[\frac{m}{p^i}]-[\frac{k}{p^i}])$ and since $[x+y]\ge [x]+[y]$, $[\frac{m+k}{p^i}]\ge [\frac{m}{p^i}]+[\frac{k}{p^i}]$for all $i\implies \forall p\in\mathbb{P}, \upsilon_p(m!k!)\le\upsilon_p((m+k)!)\implies m!k!\mid (m+k)!$. And I want to prove that there is no more solutions. Can anyone help me?

Comment: A constant sequence is also a solution, so it is false there are ni other solutions.

Comment: $\{ a_n \}$ need not be arithmetic. For example, $a_n=1$ if $n$ is odd and $a_n=2$ if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we show inductively that
$$
a_1a_2\cdots a_n \,|\, a_{l+1}a_{l+2}\cdots a_{l+n}, \quad \text{for all $\,l\ge 0$ and $n\ge 1$.}
$$
For $n=1$ is clear, since $\,a_1\,|\,a_{l+1}-a_1,\,$ and hence $\,a_1\,|\,a_{l+1}$. Assume it is true for $\,n=k$. We need to show that
$$
a_1a_2\cdots a_na_{n+1} \,|\, a_{l+1}a_{l+2}\cdots a_{l+n}a_{l+n+1}=f(l)
$$
Meanwhile, for every $j\ge 0$,
$$
f(j+1)-f(j)=(a_{j+n+2}-a_{j+1})a_{j+2}\cdots a_{j+n+1}.
$$
By the induction hypothesis, $\,a_1\cdots a_n \,|\, a_{j+2}\cdots a_{j+n+1},\,$ and is given that $\,a_{n+1} \,|\,a_{j+n+2}-a_{j+1}$. Hence
$$
a_1\cdots a_{n+1}\,|\, f(j+1)-f(j), \quad \text{for all $j\ge 0$}
$$
and since
$$
a_1\cdots a_{n+1}| f(0)=a_1\cdots a_{n+1},
$$
then
$$
a_1\cdots a_{n+1}\,|\, f(0)+\big(f(1)-f(0)\big)+\cdots+\big(f(l)-f(l-1)\big)=
f(l), \quad \text{for all $l\in\mathbb N$}
$$

Consequently,
$$
b_kb_n=(a_1\cdots a_k)(a_{1}\cdots a_{n})\,|\,  (a_1\cdots a_k)(a_{k+1}\cdot a_{k+n})=b_{k+n}.
$$